# Checking for values in a JSON formatted dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm trying to check whether a given string ("Sample1") is within the "text" field of this dictionary. What am I doing wrong?

```py
var = {'data': [{'text': 'Sample1',
                  'descriptionMoreURL': 'https://sample1.com',
                  'description': 'this is sample1',
                  'type': 'text'},
                 {'text': 'Sample2',
                  'descriptionMoreURL': 'https://sample2.com',
                  'description': 'this is sample2',
                  'type': 'text'}
                 ]}

print('Sample1' in var['data'])
```

For example, in this code I would want the output to be True. Similarly, if the string "Sample1" was replaced to "Sample2", it would also return True.

Comment: Did you notice that `text` never appears in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your checking one level higher than needed. `'Sample1'` does not exist as a key in `var['data']`, but does exist in the lower nested dictionaries.

You can use [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any) here to check if `'Sample1'` exists in each dictionaries `'text'` value:

```
>>> any(d['text'] == 'Sample1' for d in var['data'] for k in d)
True
>> any(d['text'] == 'Sample2' for d in var['data'] for k in d)
True
```

Comment: Note that this checks in *all* keys of the nested dictionaries, and not just the `text` field.

Answer (score -1):

print('Sample1' in var['data']) check your string in sequence of dict [{}, {}, {}]

try something that :

```
for el in var['data']:
   print('Sample1' in el.values())
```